# loop through (input and select) elements and check if the value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through all the (input and select) elements inside a div and check if the value is empty and then hide it

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#tabspanel").find('input[type=text] , select').each(function (){
    if (!(jQuery.trim(this.value).length > 0)) {
        this.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have used `$(this).hide()`. However, I'd suggest to filter elements first:

```
$("#tabspanel :input").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: I would probably do the `$("#tabspanel").find(...` given the right to left selector operation so you only get the ones inside the panel in the intermediate step - should be faster if the page is pretty large. +1 for the filter, what it is for!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Mine will also get the ones inside the panel only. And it should be faster than with `.find()`, since the `querySelectorAll` will do all the job.

Comment: yes, it WILL find only those I did not dispute that, it will just do: get the inputs, then from that, get only those inside the #tabspanel if my understanding of the sizzel works is correct.

Comment: tnk u so much @VisioN , i have an another problem .. i'm using your method in the ajax complet event , so don't know if i can put your filter function innside the complete function :   `$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
  $("#tabspanel :input").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
}).hide(); 
 }
 }); `

Comment: @user2077308 Why not? It will work fine. However, `success` handler is more frequently used.

Comment: @user2077308 Check your Ajax request whether it is executed correctly.

Comment: @VisioN yes , i have tried the alert msg in the complet event , it is working perfectly ,

Comment: tnks @VisioN , now it works perfectly , i just changed the div id to another inside div id

Comment: @VisioN can i use some thing like this ? `$("#customfields_1 :input").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
}).prev('td').hide();`